# Environment variables in Eclipse on OSX

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, path, environment

i have imported a certain library which executes the following command

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("svd");
```

Now in my bash shell, i can execute svd as it points to installed folder "/usr/local/bin/svd". However my java programs are unable to execute "svd" and eclipse returns with error "Cannot run program "svd": error=2, No such file or directory"

I have added the following to my environment variables in run configurations of eclipse.

```
$PATH = /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin/svd
svd = /usr/local/bin/svd
```

However eclipse still says its unable to run program "svd". Is there any way to fix this other than manually writing the full path?

```
e.g Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/usr/local/bin/svd");
```

Comment: Try wrapping the invocation in a call to BASH?

Comment: Side note: ProcessBuilder is a better way to start subprocesses than Runtime.

Comment: Yeah i could do that. But as you see the library is made to work on all platforms, hence i was expecting i could set the path on eclipse manually without modifying the source code of the library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not eclipse who cannot run the `svd` program but the `jvm`, because it cannot find `svd's` path on the system.

You should put your svd program on `$PATH` variable so that when the JVM runs your program and finds a call to svd, it should know where this `svd` program is located so it may call it.

For how to configure your $PATH variable on OSX, check here : [Setting environment variables in OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135688/setting-environment-variables-in-os-x)

I also noticed you use `Runtime` to run external programs in your java program. That is an ancient way to run external programs in java. You should consider using the `ProcessBuilder` instead. It's much more flexible, and is considered the best choice to run external programs now:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("svd");
Process p = pb.start();
//You could also read the error stream, so that when svd is not correctly set on the running system, you may alert the user.
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(line);
}

int retCode = p.waitFor();
if(retCode == 2){
    //alert the user that svd is not correctly set on PATH variable.
    LOGGER.error(sb);
    System.out.println("ERROR!! Could not run svd  because it's not correctly set on PATH variable");
}
```